# VHDL constant in generics

Tags: generics, vhdl, constants

```
entity blabla is
generic(
       register_width : integer := 32;
       --Assuming register_width > 4
       constant AVAILABLE_FOR_USER : integer := register_width - 4 --allowed in 2008     
       );
port   (
           clk : in std_logic;  
           rst : in std_logic;
           reg : out std_logic_vector(AVAILABLE_FOR_USER-1 downto 0) 
        );
end blabla;
```

What would be the reason to use a constant in a generic block if the instance can just override it?

Is there a way to create a constant based on a generic that cannot be overridden during instantiation ?

or my above example I can just substitute the calculation every time I want to use the constant, but that doesn't seem elegant and if my condition changes it could cause a lot of rework and possible errors it the code grows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer for why it is so, but probably a result of evolution of the language.

But one way to handle this, is to name the internal constants something like `PRIVATE_...`, and tell user to not map these; if users actually want to break functionality there are plenty of options, so it may be a reasonable design criteria that users will instantiate correctly if given reasonable guides.

But if you want to be certain that the private constants were not modified, then an assert is an option; even though its repeating the calculation:

```
architecture syn of blabla is
begin
 assert register_width - 4 = AVAILABLE_FOR_USER;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Thank you. That does make sense

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the calculation once:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity blabla is
generic(
       register_width : integer := 32
       );
port   (
           clk : in std_logic;  
           rst : in std_logic;
           reg : out std_logic_vector(register_width - 5 downto 0) 
        );
end blabla;

architecture blabla of blabla is
  constant AVAILABLE_FOR_USER : integer := reg'LEFT+1;   
  signal SOME_INTERNAL_SIGNAL : std_logic_vector(AVAILABLE_FOR_USER-1 downto 0);
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4AYF